# Nested For Loop conversion to Lambda & Map Comparison

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am struggling to convert an existing forloop to a lambda expression. 
I have a list of objects (`List<Task>`) which contains a map called 'InputData' (`Map<String, String>`). 
I also have another `Map<String, String>` (Acceptance).

I want to filter the list of Task objects where the Task.InputData Map contains all the 'Acceptance' map entries. Task.InputData may contain additional entries but I want to enforce the vars that exist in Acceptance must exist in Task.InputData.

The existing for loop looks like so:

```
boolean addTask;
List<Task> finalResults = new ArrayList<>();
for (Task t : results) {
      addTask = true;
      for (Entry<String, String> k : kvVars.entrySet()) {                
            if (!t.getInputData().containsKey(k) || !t.getInputData().get(k).equals(k.getValue())) {
                  addTask = false;
            }
      }

      if (addTask) {
            finalResults.add(t);
      }
}
```

I'm a bit confused about an approach, whether I should be trying to combine flatmap and filter criteria or if I should follow the logic in the existing for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` to collect all `Task`'s that having  all the 'Acceptance' k/v in InputData

```
List<Task> finalResults = results.stream()
                                 .filter(t->kvVars.entrySet()
                                                  .stream()
                                      .allMatch(k->t.getInputData().containsKey(k.getKey()) 
                                                   && t.getInputData().get(k.getKey()).equals(k.getValue()))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks Deadpool this is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set.containsAll` on the entry set of the input data map to check your condition:

```
List<Task> finalResults = results.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getInputData().entrySet().containsAll(kvVars.entrySet()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```